# Is this drain configuration correct?

Tags: plumbing, drainage

I'm moving my washing machine so I need to add drain to my line, the thing is, it's coming from the opposite side. Would it be ok to drain it that way(see image)
[image: new drain config]

---

So, looking at the answers(Thx btw), would this be better? The blue part would be venting
*(Sizes in the image are not real)*

[image: Without venting]

[image: With venting]

Comment: Where's your P?  further to the right?

Comment: Yes, my P gonna be at my washing machine vertical line

Comment: Have you considered the venting as well? Apart from the illegal Tee, you're making an S-trap unless there's a vent line above.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to update it with new information. Thanks and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that, but not with the sanitary tee fitting in your picture.  You need to use a longer sweep fitting, either a long sweep 45 or a wye.  That will change the configuration just above it, a little, and it will then look more clear that it doesn't matter that the water originally is coming from the right.

With the right fittings the water will first transition to vertical, and then to the right before entering the horizontal pipe.  With your fittings you rightly question whether that will happen efficiently.  And actually if you turn the first fitting around so it's pointing to the left that would make no difference.  It's the tee that matters.

Comment: Yup. Sanitary tee lying on its back == code violation under most codes. Some locals make exceptions if and only if it's serving a dry vent line in the upward direction. The wye is the right fitting, and rolling the wye away from dead vertical is better.

Comment: So basically, change the tee for a wye and use 3 45(or 1 90 and 1 45) to go get the drain on the opposite side of the flow?Or put the wye facing the right with a 45 to get my drain?